# calculate RX bytes and TX bytes in MB's to determine network throughput

Tags: byte, duplex, nic

ifconfig eth1 | grep -v grep | grep bytes  | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d ':' -f 2
3527285587

how do I divide the output by 1024/1024 and get the result ..

I am actually trying to calculate the RX bytes and  TX  Bytes in MB's as given in ifconfig output e.g
RX bytes:3675341313 (3.4 GiB)  TX bytes:3401591008 (3.1 GiB)

if the NIC is on 100Mb/s ( 12.MB/s) does it mean it can send and receive 12.MB/s at any given point ?? that's what I think  and how to check that real time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pipe it to "bc" provided it is installed, eg:

```
echo "$(ifconfig eth1 | grep -v grep | grep bytes | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d ':' -f 2) / 1024 / 1024" | bc
```

Comment: What is `3527285587` in that command?

Comment: @suzanshakya: Copy paste error from the OP, answer fixed.